# How can I display an ArrayList in a JTextArea

Tags: java, arraylist, jtextarea

I need to get display the elements of an ArrayList in a JTextArea including a new line after every single element. However, the code by now display all the elements in a single line, separated by commas; and openning and closing brackets "[ ]". The code by now is the following:

```
public void imprimirLista(ArrayList<Ausente> a) {
    for (Ausente s: a) {
        txtAreaAusentes.setText(a.toString());
    }
}
```

How can I print them without the commas and brakets?

Comment: Grab each element and print it rather than printing the entire list. You have a loop to get each element, but you never use it. You are also resetting the text each time through the loop when it looks like you want to append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) the text:

```
public void imprimirLista(ArrayList<Ausente> a) {
    for (Ausente s : a) {
        txtAreaAusentes.append(s.toString() + "\n"); // New line at the end
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `txtAreaAusentes.append(s.toString());` One thing I'll note is this will append to any existing text that may be in that field. If you want to clear that text, then I would change the function to

```
public void imprimirLista(ArrayList<Ausente> a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Ausente s: a) {
        sb.append(s.toString());
    }
    txtAreaAusentes.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: No need for the StringBuilder. Just append the text to the text area.

Comment: @brso05: You are correct. I missed that when I copy/pasted the original function. I edited my answer.

Comment: @camickr: See the first part of my answer. The version that uses StringBuilder is in the event that he wanted to erase any pre-existing text.

Comment: So then use setText(""); first and then use the append in the loop. There is no need to use the StringBuilder just because you want to clear the text area before appending new text.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `a` with `s` in your output:

```
String output = "";
for (Ausente s: a) {
   output += s.toString() + "\n";
}

txtAreaAusentes.setText(output);
```

Also build your output `String` first then set the text area to the `output` `String`.  You can use a `StringBuilder` if you want to be more efficient...

Comment: Don't use string concatenation. Just append the text directly to the text area.

Comment: @camickr I can use `String` concatenation if I want. There is nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Comment: @camickr infact it might be more efficient to build the `String` using a `StringBuilder` then set it once rather than append each time to the text area.

Comment: By adding one line at a time you minimize the resources required so you can support a  larger List size. That is if you first use the StringBuilder then you have 3 copies of the data, one in the List, one in the StringBuilder and then finally the text in the Document. By loading one line of text add a time into the Document you reduce the memory requirements by skipping the StringBuilder.

Comment: @camickr maybe post a test case to show how much efficiency is gained by doing it your way vs. with the `StringBuilder`.